# Why would Hive tables disappeared suddenly?

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore

When I enter `show tables;` all tables were showed on the screen as return, but when I query any of the table, it said`Table not found`... Would anyone please advise why would this happen suddenly? Suddenly means I was browsing a table in the last min and it turned out like this afterwards...

```
hive> show tables;
OK
mahoutpoc
prod
rc_agg2
rc_uum
uum
Time taken: 1.541 seconds
hive> select * from rc_uum limit 10;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'rc_uum'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `'rc_umm' != 'rc_uum'`.

Comment: Sorry it was just my typo, edited. In the system it was rc_uum, and my input was rc_uum.

Comment: @Kevin Just curious, what database are you using for the metastore?  mysql, derby, etc... ?